# change colour of a mat button when clicked in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

Hi I am developing an angular application. I want to create tabs, clicking on each calls a different function. I am using mat buttons for it. My code

```
<div flexLayout="row">
    <button mat-flat-button [color]="this.paletteColour" (click)="change()">B2-L1</button>
    <button mat-flat-button [color]="this.paletteColour" (click)="change()">B2-L3</button>
    <button mat-flat-button [color]="this.paletteColour" (click)="change()">B2-L3</button>
    <button mat-flat-button [color]="this.paletteColour" (click)="change()">B2-L4</button>

</div>
```

.ts file

```
 paletteColour
  change() {
  this.paletteColour = 'warn';
  }
```

.css file

```
.mat-flat-button {
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 0 px !important;;  
}

.mat-button, .mat-flat-button, .mat-icon-button, .mat-stroked-button { border-radius: 0px; }
```

but this changes colour of all the buttons when clicked on one button. How do I change the color of only one button that has been clicked and rest all remain the same colour.

PS : Colour change is working only when i comment background-colour in css.

Comment: It's happening cause all buttons are pointing to the same variable. You need to create a separate variable OR an array of variables that correspond to each button.

Comment: I was thinking more on lines like active, if that button is clicked only that button colour change, other buttons must remain the same

Comment: Did you try the native javascript way ?

Comment: Also, you say you're calling multiple different functions but you're actually always calling the same function.

Comment: Hi, i wish to make two function calls, one to change the colour of button, other an api call, i haven't added the other function because my main objective here is to understand how to change the colour of selected button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned you were specifically using navigation I have another solution for you; You can make angular add a class named `active` when a route is active. This is achieved by `routerLinkActive="active"`.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijn9bz

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { Page2Component } from './page2/page2.component';
import { Page3Component } from './page3/page3.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
      { path: 'page3', component: Page3Component }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, HomeComponent, Page2Component, Page3Component ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div flexLayout="row">
    <button [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="active">B2-L1</button>
    <button [routerLink]="['/page2']" routerLinkActive="active">B2-L3</button>
    <button [routerLink]="['/page3']" routerLinkActive="active">B2-L3</button>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.active{
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: What if you're not using navigation and just want to toggle between buttons and change the background color of it?

Comment: @fairlyMinty
You could encapsulate the button in a component and track its state there. ( See my other answer on this question )

Answer (score 2):

you cannot apply class(color attribute of mat) like above in angular.It should use as like below

```
 <div flexLayout="row">
          <button mat-flat-button [attr.color]="this.selected == 1 ? 'warn' : 'primary'" (click)="change(1)">B2-L1</button>
          <button mat-flat-button [attr.color]="this.selected == 2 ? 'warn' : 'primary'" (click)="change(2)">B2-L3</button>
          <button mat-flat-button [attr.color]="this.selected == 3 ? 'warn' : 'primary'" (click)="change(3)">B2-L3</button>
          <button mat-flat-button [attr.color]="this.selected == 4 ? 'warn' : 'primary'" (click)="change(4)">B2-L4</button>
      </div>

change(n) {
    this.paletteColour = 'warn';
    this.selected=n;
  }
```

Comment: inspect html and see class name is changing or not?

Comment: yes class name is changing, but the color is not changing

Comment: have you linked material style sheet in your project.is material button working in other components of your project?

Comment: material button is working, but the colour is not changing :(

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirment, first you need to know which tab is active and then apply color only for that tab,for that purpose you need to have another variable **currentActiveTab**.
You need to change the currentActiveTab value whenever user clicks on a different tab using change method and this will activate the color of tab by passing the tab index as param to the method.

```
<div flexLayout="row">
    <button mat-flat-button [color]="this.crrentActiveTab == 1 ? this.paletteColour : null" (click)="change(1)">B2-L1</button>
    <button mat-flat-button [color]="this.crrentActiveTab == 2 ? this.paletteColour : null" (click)="change(2)">B2-L3</button>
    <button mat-flat-button [color]="this.crrentActiveTab == 3 ? this.paletteColour : null" (click)="change(3)">B2-L3</button>
    <button mat-flat-button [color]="this.crrentActiveTab == 4 ? this.paletteColour : null" (click)="change(4)">B2-L4</button>
</div>
```

Here you will be setting the paleteinside the ts change method

```
 change(index) {
  this.currentActiveTab = index;
 }
```

Comment: Hi thank you. I have added ` this.paletteColour = 'warn';` in the change function. But I am not able to change the color .

Answer (score 1):

You could put the buttons in their own components. I made a quick demo with a simple button. I am sure it works similar with angular material.

A major advantage is that this also separates functionality instead of making a component class that does everything.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-button',
  template: '<button [style.background]="this.color" (click)="toggleColor()">I am button #1</button>'
})
export class MyButtonComponent  {
  color = 'red';

  constructor(){}

  toggleColor(){
    if( this.color === 'red' )
      this.color = 'blue';
    else
      this.color = 'red';
  }
}
```

Play around with it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y8zf5a

Note: Personally I would not colour the buttons based on a button-click, but change the buttons class to indicate the availability of the function, which the button calls. So you would have classes like unavailable, processing, available, processed, etc. that reflect the state of the button. These classes would be styled with css.

Comment: HI, this changes the color of the button from red to blue when clicked, but when i click on the other button, the blue is still there, i want only button to be blue

Comment: @cvg I must have misunderstood the question then. I assumed that you wanted a row of buttons that you can interact with independently. What are you trying to achieve?Are the buttons navigation buttons related to a specific path?

Comment: HI @RMo , yes they are navigation buttons to specific paths

Answer (score 0):

use `deep`

```
 .mat-flat-button  /deep/ .mat-button-focus-overlay {
          background-color: grey;
          border-radius: 0 px !important;; 
    }
```

this will override the default style

Comment: not working :( , in fact the the grey background is also not being applied now

Comment: a) /deep/ is not used anymore; prefer ::ng-deep  b) even ::ng-deep is deprecated and Google *say* that browsers will eventually drop support.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way

.html

```
<div flexLayout="row">
    <div flexLayout="row">
        <button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == 1 ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="change(1)">B2-L1</button>
        <button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == 2 ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="change(2)">B2-L3</button>
        <button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == 3 ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="change(3)">B2-L3</button>
        <button mat-flat-button [ngClass]="this.selected == 4 ? 'tab_selected' : 'tab_unselected'" (click)="change(4)">B2-L4</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

.ts

```
selected
change(n) {
  this.paletteColour = 'warn';
  this.selected=n;
  console.log(this.selected);
}
```

.css

```
   .tab_selected {
    background-color: grey; 
    border-radius: 0 px !important;;  
}

 .mat-button {
  border-radius: 0 px !important;;     
}
```

Thank you all for the support.

Answer (score 0):

- Ver easy solution would be like the following:-
- Just use `routeLinkActive='active'` and set a class in the component css called active.

  ```
       <button 
           mat-raised-button 
           color="primary" 
           *appHasRole="'admin'" 
           routerLink="/admin"
           routerLinkActive="active"
           [routerLinkActiveOptions]={exact:true}
           >Home
       </button>
  ```